# Remote Debugging can't be remove from Ionic App after Release on Play Store

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using Ionic to build hybrid application.I already made my publishing version and upload on Play store. But when I inspect that app after downloaded from playstore it show all the code of that in chrome inspect so this is very big security risk.Anyone have any idea about how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing you can do.. is to minfied and obfuscate your js code (and also minified your css)... for the HMTL ..one possibile solution is to put HTML teplates in angularCache (so it give you also performance boost) ..cause it's more difficulty to read... i think tehre are not other options

Comment: Can you suggest me proper way to minify? and where is anfgularCache?

Comment: the proper way is to do with tools like GULP (http://gulpjs.com/) with other plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify and for put html in cache use https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache

Comment: http://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-minify-an-ionic-application-for-production/

I done all this job but when i run it shows whole app as it is in chrome as before its too much panic and ionic has no meaning!!